# Excel: Completely basic forumla use

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is super basic, so sorry for that:

If I insert this formula (f.ex.)

```
=CELL("address")
```

it shows the current cell address/position - f.ex. $E$5

However, if I insert the same forumula in the row below, the result in both cells change.
So, it doesn't show the correct value if I use it more than once. How do I solve this super-basic excel "thing"?

If I f.ex. insert the formula in cells E5 and E6, both cells will show $E$6, instead of $E$5 and $E$6.

EDIT:

I got an answer below, saying that this formula should be used instead:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())
```

However, this just results in Excel complaining about the forumla having an error...?

EDIT 2:

Replace "," with ";", and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cell` formula is not the correct formula to get the adress of your cell unless you specify the cells reference as the second argument of the function - But since that is what you want in the first place, the easier way to do it (although there are MANY other ways to do it too), would be:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That gives an error.

Comment: It works when using semi colon instead of comma.

Comment: The semicolon vs comma issue is due to your Regional Settings and selected list separator character (check Control Panel). The answer given is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try =Cell("address",E5) then copy it to other cells: if you don't give a reference Cell gives information about the currently selected cell.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cell.php

If the range parameter is omitted, the CELL function will assume that you are retrieving information for the last cell that was changed.